# Kafka Consume Poll

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer; 
Details as follows:

```
Version="0.10.0.0"
auto.offset.reset.config="earliest"
enable.auto.commit="false"
```

When I check the offsets for the consumer using the consumeroffsetchecker I see there is a a message lag of 1 and a total message count of 9

Question
When I poll the consumer with a timeout of 3 seconds, no messages come back even though there is 1 message in the queue that has not been consumed by the consumer (as evidenced by the consumeroffsetchecker).
I manually control commits. My Poll loop is as follows:

```
        while (true)
        {

            ConsumerRecords<String, T> records = _consumer.poll(3000);
            for (TopicPartition partition : records.partitions())
            {
                _logger.info("Found Kafka Messages");
                List<ConsumerRecord<String, T>> partitionRecords = records.records(partition);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, T> record : partitionRecords)
                {
                    _logger.info("Message Received - Partition: {} Offset: {} - Topic {}", record.partition(), record.offset(), record.topic());
                    try
                    {
                        processMessage(record.value());
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        _logger.error("Error processing Message - Partition: {} Offset: {} - Topic {}", record.partition(), record.offset(), record.topic(), exc);
                    }
                }

                long lastoffset = partitionRecords.get(partitionRecords.size() - 1).offset();
                _logger.info("Committing Kafka Offset - {} Offset {} - Topic {}", lastoffset + 1, partition,  topics.get(0) );
                _consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(partition, new OffsetAndMetadata(lastoffset + 1)));
            }
        }
```

I believe the message has not been committed because its shows as "lagging" in the offset checker

Any ideas why the poll does not pick up the message ??

FYI if I put a message on the queue after that message gets picked up but the one in lag gets lost ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you commit the offsets? The committed offset should always be the offset of the next message that your application will read.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? I have the same issue